# pre caching the second image from php script

Tags: php, javascript, image, preload

I have my html like this:

```
<html>
<body>
         <script src="http://example.com/a.js"></script>
         <img src="loading.gif" />

</body>
</html>
```

now I have a php script which outputs a png image.

What i want is to :

1. Pre-load/Pre-cache the png image from the php script.
2. When every thing is loaded(the page,images, external js,..) then i need
       to call a function defined in a.js
3. after calling the function, I
       need to display the preloaded image (replacing the loading.gif)

How do i achieve this? Please help

Comment: try placing image in img tag with display none

Answer (score 0):

You can preload image with JavaScript Image object:

```
var img = new Image();
img.src = 'path/to/image.png';
```

Now the image is cached. You can simple append tag with this image to document and your image will be shown immediately.